# Handling XML data with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, alamofire

I started to use cocoapods with my current ios project. I need to use SOAP to get content with easy way for my ios project. I have googled it and Alamofire pod is great for me. Because I am using Swift programming language.

I have inited easily this pod. But my web services return me XML result. And I want to serialisation to array this XML result. But I can't.

When I call my web service with a browser I get this kind of result

[image]

Alamofire response method is like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://my-web-service-domain.com", parameters: nil)
         .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                     println(request)
                     println(response)
                     println(error)
                   }
```

When I run this method I see this output on the terminal:

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x170010a30> { URL: http://my-web-service-domain.com }
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1704276c0> { URL: http://my-web-service-domain.com } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Length" = 1020;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 18 Jun 2015 10:57:07 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} })
nil
```

I want to get result to an array which see on browser to show my storyboard.
Can anybody help me how to serialise this data with Alamofire framework or Swift language?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand your description, I think you would like to get the XML data and parse it, right? Regarding to this, you may handle with wrong variables in the response callback. You should `println(data)` to check the XML document.

For parsing XML data, you could consider [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash). The Alamofire request could look like:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://my-web-service-domain.com", parameters: nil)
         .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(data) // if you want to check XML data in debug window.
            var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
            println(xml["UserDTO"]["FilmID"].element?.text) // output the FilmID element.
         }
```

Further information about XML management, please check [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash).

Comment: the best answer. Works with alamofire 3

Comment: It is working fine. But my response has few special characters. So it is giving me exception "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 7):

**Alamofire 4.x - Swift 3.x**:

(please note that in this example I've used `URLEncoding.default` instead of `URLEncoding.xml` because the `xml` parameter exclude the possibility to pass parameters and headers, so `default` is more confortable.)

```
let url = "https://httpbin.org/get"
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
.responseString { response in
    print(" - API url: \(String(describing: response.request!))")   // original url request
    var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
        if let string = response.result.value {
            print("XML: \(string)")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        statusCode = error._code // statusCode private
        print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
        print(error)
    }
}
```

---

**Alamofire 3.0** october 2015 and Xcode 7 according to the 3.0.0-beta.3 [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/3.0.0-beta.3#response-handling) and the [Alamofire 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md).

For me the correct syntax is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responsePropertyList { response in

            if let error = response.result.error {
                print("Error: \(error)")

                // parsing the data to an array
            } else if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: String]] {

                if array.isEmpty {
                    print("No data")

                } else { 
                    //Do whatever you want to do with the array here
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want a good **XML** parser, please take a look to [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash).

An example could be: 
`let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(string)`

Comment: and Alamofire 4.5 ?

Comment: I thought you have a magical method to parse it via Alamofire and not the use of 3rd part API :X

Comment: You can leave the encoding blank and nothing would change. This is not an answer. That library was mentioned multiple times here.

Comment: @6rchid You speaking about an old answer (5 years ago), so you can't analize that code with your modern compiler and the current situation. In that period , that library was the best to handling XML, today we are in another world sir. Next time ask for an help, this should be helpful than downgrading oldest post without a valid reason.

Answer (score 6):

Using Alamofire 3.0 current version as of Sept 2015 and Xcode 7.

The implementation bellow has the advantage of not using an additional external library such as SWXMLHash

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, encoding: .PropertyList(.XMLFormat_v1_0, 0)).responsePropertyList { request, response, result in

//Note that result have two properties: error and value as of Alamofire 3.0, check the migration guide for more info

  if let error = result.error {
    print("Error: \(error)")

    // parsing the data to an array 
  } else if let array = result.value as? [[String: String]] {

    if array.isEmpty {
      print("No data")

    } else { 
      //Do whatever you want to do with the array here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map the XML to swift objects, you may also consider  [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper). (uses the same technique as the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper))

Create your model by implementing `XMLMappable` protocol:

```
class UserDTO: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var extensionData: String?
    var canChangeDeviceConfig: BooleanAtttribute?
    var canChangeDriverConfig: BooleanAtttribute?
    var canChangeFleetConfig: BooleanAtttribute?
    var canChangeGeofenceConfig: BooleanAtttribute?
    var canSaveHistory: BooleanAtttribute?
    var canViewReport: BooleanAtttribute?
    var canWatchHistory: BooleanAtttribute?
    var deliverDailyReportByEmail: BooleanAtttribute?
    var deliverDailyReportBySms: BooleanAtttribute?
    var email: String?
    var firm: String?
    var firmId: Int?
    var firstName: String?
    var id: Int?
    var isActive: Bool?
    var isAdmin: Bool?
    var lastName: String?
    var phone: String?
    var recivesDailyReport: BooleanAtttribute?
    var userName: String?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        extensionData <- map["ExtensionData"]
        canChangeDeviceConfig <- map["CanChangeDeviceConfig"]
        canChangeDriverConfig <- map["CanChangeDriverConfig"]
        canChangeFleetConfig <- map["CanChangeFleetConfig"]
        canChangeGeofenceConfig <- map["CanChangeGeofenceConfig"]
        canSaveHistory <- map["CanSaveHistory"]
        canViewReport <- map["CanViewReport"]
        canWatchHistory <- map["CanWatchHistory"]
        deliverDailyReportByEmail <- map["DeliverDailyReportByEmail"]
        deliverDailyReportBySms <- map["DeliverDailyReportBySms"]
        email <- map["Email"]
        firm <- map["Firm"]
        firmId <- map["FirmId"]
        firstName <- map["FirstName"]
        id <- map["Id"]
        isActive <- (map["IsActive"], BooleanTransformeType(trueValue: "true", falseValue: "false"))
        isAdmin <- (map["IsAdmin"], BooleanTransformeType(trueValue: "true", falseValue: "false"))
        lastName <- map["LastName"]
        phone <- map["Phone"]
        recivesDailyReport <- map["RecivesDailyReport"]
        userName <- map["UserName"]
    }
}

class BooleanAtttribute: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var booleanValue: Bool?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        booleanValue <- (map.attributes["xsi:nil"], BooleanTransformeType(trueValue: "true", falseValue: "false"))
    }
}

class Firm: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var extensionData: String?
    var firmTypeId: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var parentFirmId: Int?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        extensionData <- map["ExtensionData"]
        firmTypeId <- map["FirmTypeId"]
        id <- map["Id"]
        name <- map["Name"]
        parentFirmId <- map["ParentFirmId"]
    }
}

class BooleanTransformeType<T: Equatable>: XMLTransformType {
    typealias Object = Bool
    typealias XML = T

    private var trueValue: T
    private var falseValue: T

    init(trueValue: T, falseValue: T) {
        self.trueValue = trueValue
        self.falseValue = falseValue
    }

    func transformFromXML(_ value: Any?) -> Bool? {
        if let value = value as? T {
            return value == trueValue
        }
        return nil
    }

    func transformToXML(_ value: Bool?) -> T? {
        if value == true {
            return trueValue
        }
        return falseValue
    }
}
```

And use the `XMLMapper` class to map the XML string into the model objects:

```
let userDTO = XMLMapper<UserDTO>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Altenatively you can use [Requests](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper#requests-subspec) subspec and the `responseXMLObject(completionHandler:)` function to map the response directly into the model objects:

```
Alamofire.request("http://my-web-service-domain.com", method: .get).responseXMLObject { (response: DataResponse<UserDTO>) in
    let userDTO = response.result.value
    print(userDTO?.id ?? "nil")
}
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a really unique issue where the server returned an XML that has a JSON as a string. Hope it will help someone.

Basically the XML looked like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{"Response":{"Status":"success","Result_Count":"1","Error_Description":"","Result":{"Login_result":{"user_id":"1","user_type":"1","user_name":"h4cked","user_locked":"False","user_locked_message":""}}}}</string>
```

As you can see the actual JSON is the `{"Response":....`

The solution is based only on Alamofire 4.4.

What you need to do is this:

1. Use the `.responsePropertyList`
2. Check for error
3. Convert the value to Data
4. Serialize to JSON object
5. Cast to Dictionary `[String : Any]`

Here it is:

```
Alamofire.request(NetworkAPIPaths.pathForLogin(),
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: [APIParameters.userName.rawValue : "",
                                   APIParameters.password.rawValue : ""]).responsePropertyList
        { (response : DataResponse<Any>) in

    if let error = response.result.error
    {
        // Error...
    }
    else if let jsonFullString = response.result.value as? String
    {
        if let jsonStringAsData = jsonFullString.data(using: .utf8)
        {
            do
            {
                let jsonGhost = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonStringAsData, options: [])

                if let actualJSON = jsonGhost as? [String : Any]
                {
                   // actualJSON is ready to be parsed :)
                }
             }
             catch
             {
               print (error.localizedDescription)
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tsaiid's answer in Swift 3 and Alamofire 4:

```
Alamofire.request("http://my-web-service-domain.com", parameters: nil) //Alamofire defaults to GET requests
     .response { response in
        if let data = response.data {
          println(data) // if you want to check XML data in debug window.
          var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
          println(xml["UserDTO"]["FilmID"].element?.text) // output the FilmID element.
        }
     }
```

Comment: swift 3 has no println

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use **different decoders (JSON, URL, XML)** with Alamofire, the best and simplest way I found was using [XMLCoder](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder).

- **Alamofire 5**
- **Swift 5**

*(It will probably work on older versions)*

---

On the Alamofire's response decodable method, you just need to use **XMLDecoder()**

```
@discardableResult
public func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(of type: T.Type = T.self,
                                            ...
                                            decoder: DataDecoder = JSONDecoder(),
                                            ...
                                            completionHandler: @escaping (AFDataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
```

Something like this:

```
import XMLCoder

...

dataRequest
    .validate()
    .responseDecodable(of: T.self, decoder: XMLDecoder()) { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
```

And your models just need to conform the **Codable** protocol.

```
import Foundation

class ReportModel: Codable {
    var connections: ConnectionModel?
    var notifications: NotificationsModel?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case connections
        case notifications
    }
}
```

---

I created a **GIST** with a complete structure of how you can decode XML using Alamofire and I added some examples with nested objects and XML attributes.

- https://gist.github.com/Enriquecm/bedf024d8a8f519eb1185fef14adcec3

---