# Get Response of XML HTTP url using alamofire and Swift4 IOS

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4

I am developing an application in which I need to get the response code of a HTTP URL, The URL returns an xml which is encrypted. I only need to get that encrypted response code into a variable. 
I've used Alamofire for http request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980470/8069241

Comment: I tried it.. But since Iam using swift latest version, it did't work. I've installed SWXML hash using cocoapods. I tried to upgrade the code to swift4, but showing error!! @maxwell

Comment: Actually, the URL should returns an xml response, which I am not able to print in console

Comment: have you looked at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913594/handling-xml-data-with-alamofire-in-swift

Comment: @Neha I tried that too.. since they are old version code, it didn't work.. I was trying with SWXML itself. I tried to alter the code into the latest methods, still they show error.!!!

Comment: I'll give an example of the problem that I face... I have a URL which when called actually returns an XML which is just an encrypted key.(that doesn't matter). Using Alamofire I tried to send a http request with that URL. It shows successful URL hit, But the response Iam getting is something else. I don't get a xml response.

Comment: @Neha Thanks Neha and Maxwell for giving a solution. That code just needed some alteration and it worked fine...Thanks for helping me out.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alamofire.request("URL Goes here",method:.get)
 .response { response in
    if let data = response.data {
      print(data)
      var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
      print(xml["e1"]["e2"].element?.text)
    }
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer Swift has libraries like SwiftyJSON for JSON handling while XMLParsing and getting XML response is a bit confusing. So in a context where we want to get the XML response of a URL in IOS (Swift), we can use SWXMLHash(i think it's an external third-party library) for doing the same.. It's pretty simple as it explains...! :)